# Disabling input tags and focusing on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setfocus, disabled-input

I have a code here for disabling the radio on a form and focusing on the submit button right after the timer expires. But this code seems not to work. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code or if you have any alternative with this? I'm using jquery timeTo plugin as my timer ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#countdown').timeTo(5000, disablefocus();  
  }); 
});

function disablefocus(){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true);
$('#submitWidget').focus();
});
</script>
```

---->

```
<div id='countdown'></div>
<form>
<input type='radio' name='radio1' value='father'>
<input type = 'submit' id ='submitwidget' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes it's working now. But can you help me a little about CSS regarding to this. I want to change the background to grey and some little animation to side of the button saying that he needs to click it.

`<span>'You have to click me now!'</span><input type = 'submit' id ='submitwidget' value='submit'/>`

Comment: i've try putting this but nothing happens

`$(document).ready(function() {
$('#countdown').timeTo(20, function() { disablefocus();}); 

function disablefocus(){
var message = document.getElementById('#confirmMessage');
var goodColor = "#66cc66";
$('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true);
$('#submitWidget').focus();

 message.style.color = goodColor;
 message.innerHTML = "Press me now!"
}
});`

Comment: Why you use half javscript and another jquery.

Comment: oh sorry bout that man, but i've already solve the problem with the css. i'll try posting it after i'd got home.

Answer (score 0):

> you add extra curly braces for timeTo function and miss the closed curly braces for disableFocus function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#countdown').timeTo(5000, disablefocus); 

function disablefocus(){

$('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true);
$('#submitWidget').focus();

}

});
```

or another way

```
$('#countdown').timeTo(5000, function() { disablefocus(); });
```

Comment: i need to show the clock ticking that's why i use plug-ins. And also, can this a little animation like the radio buttons will turn grey to notify the user that it is disabled?

Comment: $('#countdown').timeTo(5000, disablefocus); Replace the line and check

Comment: You put extra one curly braces for that scenario.

Comment: and please remove document .ready in function disablefocus . Use document ready once

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#countdown').timeTo(20, function() { 

            disablefocus(); 

 });

 function disablefocus(){ 

     var message = $('#confirmMessage'); 
     var goodColor = "#66cc66"; 
     $('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true);
     $('#submitWidget').focus(); 
     message.css("color" , goodColor); 
     message.html("Press me now!");

     }
});
```

Comment: can u tell me what is the use of timeTo plugin. Is the syntax is right?